# Find Github repo's where Notifications/Watching set to "Participating and @mentions"

Tags: github, notifications

I was setting up my notifications for the repo's for our GitHub Enterprise instance on the `https://<server-name>/watching` page ... setting some to "Participating and @mention", "Ignore", etc.

Now when I look at the `watching` page I see 3 groupings

- **Watching** - under here are the repos where I set "All Activity"
- **Custom** - under here are the repos  where I set Custom
- **Ignoring** - under here are the repos where I set "Ignore"

But what is not listed are the repos where I set them to "Participating and @mention".  I thought these repos would be listed under their own group or maybe under "Watching".

Note I also tried on github.com and see the same behavior.

How can I find which repos I set to "Participating and @mention"?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also stuck there!